# What does a series of long beeps indicate when you switch on your PC?

Tags: boot, bootrepair

My Windows 7 PC powers on  but does not load and start when I press the power button. I hear a series of long beeps, each beep lasting for about 2 seconds. After a minute or so, the PC attempts to restart on its own and fails again.

I do not see any error message on the display. However, only the very first time, the screen lit up and showed what looked like gibberish all over.

I felt this could be due to faulty hard drive or DVD drive. So I unplugged them from the motherboard and tried to turn the PC on. Nothing changed and the issue continues.

What would you say could be causing this?

Comment: Its a POST (Power On Self Test) beep code. check the computer and/or motherboard manufacturers documentation or google for the motherboard manual.  usually its a repeating series of long and/or short beeps.

Comment: A friend recently had a similar issue with an aging Compaq laptop. The motherboard apparently died, it was temporarily fixed by "reflowing" it in a kitchen oven, which brought it back to life for a few months. A 2nd reflow failed. He noted that the PC would beep numerous times, and that the monitor wouldn't power on. There are beep codes which mean different things depending on the length and tones of the beeps, etc.

Comment: You won't get beeps for faulty HD, or even no HD, but you will for no monitor, bad RAM etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decipher the beep code you need to know who the BIOS manufacturer is for your particular Motherboard.  The BIOS is the Basic Input Output Services chip that is the "traffic cop" for your MB that directs things.  When you turn your computer on it goes through POST or Power On Self Test.  If you get one short beep and your computer turns on it has tested memory and power and other components and has passed operation over to the Hard Disk Drive (HDD) to load the operating system into memory.

Go to your Motherboard manual, look up the model number online, or open the case and see if you can see the Motherboard model stamped on a corner or the inside of the board.  Then look it up online.

Here is a reference chart also to help with beep codes if you can determine the BIOS chip you have.  Typical Manufacturers are AMI, Phoenix, Award, etc.  Sometimes it shows up on your screen when you start the computer, depending on how your BIOS boot settings are configured.

http://www.technick.net/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=guide_beep_codes

Comment: Thanks. I'm on it. It definitely looks like a motherboard issue. Power On Self Test fails. Hopefully, I will find out what exactly these beeps are trying to tell me.

Comment: It turned out that the CMOS battery had gone dry. I replaced it with a new one and the issue was resolved. One of the beep error codes listed on the page you linked said that POST could fail as a result of the machine being unable to recover CMOS data. I can't say I understood it correctly, but I decided to replace the CMOS battery and see if it would resolve the issue. Luckily it did.